# Average QRgb values

Tags: qt, colors, average

For a posterization algorithmn I'm going to need to average the color values (`QRgb`) present in my `std::vector`.

How would you suggest to do it? Sum the 3 components separately then average them? Otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [`QRgb`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qcolor.html#QRgb-typedef) is just a 32-bit unsigned int in ARGB format it doesn't suffice for adding colors, which will most likely result in overflow. But also [`QColor`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qcolor.html) doesn't suffice as it uses fixed-point 16-bit integers for the color components and therefore also cannot cope with colors out of the valid [0,1] range. So you cannot use `QRgb` or `QColor` for this as they clamp each partial sum to the valid range. Neither can you predivide the colors before adding them because of their limited precision.

So your best bet would really just be to sum up the individual components using floating point numbers and then divide them by the vector size:

```
std::vector<QRgb> rgbValues;

float r = 0.0f, g = 0.0f, b = 0.0f, a = 0.0f;
for(std::vector<QRgb>::const_iterator iter=rgbValues.begin(); 
    iter!=rgbValues.end(); ++iter)
{
    QColor color(*iter);
    r += color.redF();
    g += color.greenF();
    b += color.blueF();
    a += color.alphaF();
}

float scale = 1.0f / float(rgbValues.size());
QRgb = QColor::fromRgbF(r*scale, g*scale, b*scale, a*scale).rgba();
```

Comment: That's what I tried. I used long long to store des sums as I was using [0-255] values